# does angular2-beta.0 really cache the view?

Tags: caching, angular, sample, forward-compatibility, angular-new-router

> SPEED & PERFORMANCE
>
> Angular 2 is dramatically faster than Angular 1 with support for fast
>   initial loads through server-side pre-rendering, offline compile for
>   fast startup, and ultrafast change detection and view caching for
>   smooth virtual scrolling and snappy view transitions.

The features look great, but a normal requirement is that when I navigate from `ListComponent` to `ViewComponent`, I want keep the `ListComponent` cached so when I click back from `ViewComponent`, the `ListComponent` doesn't need to rerender(`ListComponent` often gets AJAX data from page 2,３, etc. I know I can keep the data in a service and store the `scrollPosition` when I click back, but it will rerender the data again. I really think caching it is a better way.

I implement `CanReuse`, but it dosn't work, it only works when navigating between `ViewComponents`. So., I want know how the `ListComponent` to `ViewComponent` caching can work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ProtoViewRef](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ProtoViewRef-class.html) class:

> A ProtoView is a prototypical View that is the result of Template compilation and is used by Angular to efficiently create an instance of this View based on the compiled Template.
>
> Most ProtoViews are created and used internally by Angular and you don't need to know about them, except in advanced use-cases where you compile components yourself via the low-level Compiler API.
>
> Example
>
> Given this template:

```
Count: {{items.length}}
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="var item of items">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
```

> Angular desugars and compiles the template into two ProtoViews:

- Outer ProtoView:

  ```
  Count: {{items.length}}
  <ul>
    <template ngFor var-item [ngForOf]="items"></template>
  </ul>
  ```
- Inner ProtoView:

  ```
  <li>{{item}}</li>
  ```

> Notice that the original template is broken down into two separate ProtoViews.

**References**

- [Angular2 Issue #1492: Allow transplanting of <template> ProtoViews into other ViewContainers](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1492)
- [Angular2 Issue #2529: Implement new content reprojection](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2529)
- [Angular2 Issue #1351: Refactor DynamicComponentLoader/Compiler/Renderer to support user views and make them more consistent](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1351)
- [Angular2 feat(core): add syntax sugar to make @View optional](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/bd31b0169066c22236fd9ca157323a87b68cfdd6)